# bluetooth stops working - "Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed"

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

#### Error description

i want to use my bluetooth mouse. simple as that. so i connected the mouse with my notebook - at first it worked fine, but after several minutes it suddenly stopped working and it will not start until rebooting.

so i rebooted my notebook, and at system start everything works fine, but again after a few minutes my mouse stops working.

#### useful information

general information

```
OS: Ubuntu 17.04 x86_64 
Model: W840SU Series 
Kernel: 4.10.0-21-generic 
DE: Budgie 
WM: Mutter(Budgie) 
CPU: Intel i5-4200U (4) @ 2.6GHz 
GPU: Intel Haswell Mobile 
Memory: 3500MiB / 7870MiB
```

`lsusb`:                                        :

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:0536 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0eef:a122 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root
```

#### right after system start:

[output from hciconfig, bluetoothctl and rfkill](https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/soraphis/qnLra/fc51e7b86bcf02a98ea9475cd612c4aaabd7f27e/files/console_output1)

#### right after mouse stopped working

[output from hciconfig, bluetoothctl and rfkill](https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/soraphis/qnLra/fc51e7b86bcf02a98ea9475cd612c4aaabd7f27e/files/console_output2)

[output from `syslog`](https://bitbucket.org/!api/2.0/snippets/soraphis/qnLra/fc51e7b86bcf02a98ea9475cd612c4aaabd7f27e/files/syslog)

```
dmesg | grep Blue
[    5.049999] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.050029] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.050032] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.050034] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.050041] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.202899] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710010002030d56
[    5.202900] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel device is already patched. patch num: 56
[    5.209461] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.209463] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.209468] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   29.802314] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   29.802320] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   29.802325] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   33.640917] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   33.640923] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   33.648277] input: Bluetooth Mouse M557 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:046D:B010.0002/input/input24
[   33.651568] hid-generic 0005:046D:B010.0002: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v10.01 Mouse [Bluetooth Mouse M557] on a0:88:69:15:35:82
[  998.091592] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0804 tx timeout
[ 1010.060391] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[ 1292.746097] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0406 tx timeout
[ 1297.962695] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc3f tx timeout
[ 1303.211103] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[ 1305.227339] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c13 tx timeout
[ 1306.187346] Bluetooth: hci0: turning off Intel device LED failed (-110)
[ 1528.198244] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be87115af00 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 1539.090928] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be94d2df9c0 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 1548.147837] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be94d2df9c0 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 1559.176769] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be94ef6c6c0 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 1780.029401] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be94f8b96c0 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 2167.226568] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be7b54c7900 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 2207.166935] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be88efea480 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 2483.163077] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be79f86f3c0 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 2493.148010] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be8d338a540 failed to resubmit (113)
[ 4388.304302] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff9be76b0f89c0 failed to resubmit (113)
```

---

this might be the interesting part:

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Comment: I had org.bluez.Error.Blocked when I typed `power on` and that turns out to be fixable by doing the first thing here: `rfkill unblock bluetooth` https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/180#issuecomment-170236915

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to use my Logitech K380 bluetooth keyboard, I had the same issues as Soraphis. Uninstalling TLP from my system ultimately solved it for me.

Try disabling or uninstalling TLP if you have it installed.

Comment: What is “TLP” and how do you uninstall it? Do you mean the package `tlp` and uninstalling with `sudo apt remove tlp`?

Answer (score 0):

Since it can't reach hci0:

```
hciconfig hci0 up
```

could do the trick.

Comment: `Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it was doing this but I got it to work without restarting by running `bluethoothctl`, turning the `power off`, then `power on` (which failed), then exiting with `quit`, and trying `power off` and `power on` again.

```
user@ubuntu:~$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]# quit
[DEL] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF ubuntu [default]

user@ubuntu:~$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF ubuntu [default]
[NEW] Device 11:22:33:44:55:66 Some device
[NEW] Device 11:22:33:44:55:77 Another device
[bluetooth]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Class: 0x1c010c
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Powered: yes
[CHG] Controller AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF Discovering: yes
```

Hope it helps!